# How can I mix Dirt surface with normal Color in Principled Shader?

Tags: materials, shaders

I want to make something dirty but I don't know how to mix a surface texture with the new Principled Shader?

[image]

Comment: This should help https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4H5W6C_Mbck

Comment: not really, because he had finished shader with rust on it

Comment: You could always just use another principled shader and mix the two of them with a mix node. Then use your texture as as the mix factor. I will try to post an answer later to help you out.